# Get built-in function details/usage

Tags: php

In PHP I can able to retrieve all the built-in functions using PHP function called `get_defined_functions`.

So this function returns all the Internal and user-defined functions as an array.

I wonder how to get the function usage for this array of function names

In some editor when I type a function name, it will give a tooltip stating the usage of the entered function.

Is there any way to achieve this in PHP code

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "usage"? Do you mean the whole documentation as like on https://www.php.net/strlen? Or a list of parameters and return values? Or a short description? Please elaborate on what you mean/want and what the problem is.

Comment: I mean to get a short description, and if possible parameters and return values also will help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectiontype.php) to get information about a function. As a test you can use the following code:

```
<?php
$data = new ReflectionFunction('strlen');
$parameters = $data->getParameters();
$doc = $data->getDocComment();
$return = $data->getReturnType();
var_dump($parameters, $doc, $return);
```

This will get you the following output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(ReflectionParameter)#2 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "str"
  }
}
bool(false)
NULL
```

However, you might not get all the information you want when you try to read the information from internal functions. As an example, the documentation of [`getReturnType()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getreturntype.php) states:

> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> null
> ```
>
> This is because many internal functions do not have types specified for their parameters or return values. It is therefore best to avoid using this method on built-in functions.

Comment: Is it possible to get the short description for function 'strlen', because in your output its missing

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi As I said, you might not. These information are most likely not available in the compiled PHP binary/library anymore.